# How to use dual whatsapp in Lumia 535 running WP8.1?

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, nokia-lumia-535, dual-sim

I have recently migrated from android platform and there I was using multiple WhatsApp accounts on a single phone using third party applications but since windows is a closed platform, can I use a separate WhatsApp account for each SIM on my Lumia 535 DS running on windows phone 8.1? I didn't find any such app in the store (Sorry for my bad English).

Comment: As much as I know there is only one WhatsApp app, the official one. It's doesn't support multiple accounts so there is no way right now to use more than one Whatsapp accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible now. One willing to use two WhatsApp accounts simultaneously can install :

1. WhatsApp
2. WhatsApp Beta

Both available at store to install. Reference: Answer of linked question.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's not that easy on a windows phone, but there is a way.

Here is how you can do it,

1. Make a backup of your current main whatsapp, just in case something
   goes wrong. (This version will remain in your phone memory)
2. Download the mod Whatsapp WPH. Download link can be found in this [article](http://winphonehub.org/interop-how-to-use-multiple-whatsapp-on-a-single-windows-phone/).
3. Connect phone to pc and deploy mod Whatsapp WPH using Application
   deloyment tool. (Make sure u have selected sdcard to install new
   apps in storage sense).
4. Now whatsapp WPH will be deloyed to sd card.
5. Open whatsapp WPH and verify the account with your 2nd number.
6. Now it will ask you to restore messages from ur main whatsapp
   backup. Select restore.
7. Done. now you have 2 versions of whatsapp on your phone. Both will work as separate app, including notifications and live tiles.

Have a look at the following links(1st link is suiotable only for W10M) :

1. http://windowspcguide.com/use-two-whatsapp-accounts-in-one-mobile-phone/
2. http://winphonehub.org/interop-how-to-use-multiple-whatsapp-on-a-single-windows-phone/

Comment: the first u provided isnt relevant.

Comment: I already had a look on that. It's for W10M not for WP8.

Comment: Please summarise the links in your post. Link-only answers can easily become useless if the link ever changes or becomes unavailable. For more information, see [How do I write a good answer?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Indrek I have summarised the links in the post. But @ Patrick the **download link** for *mod Whatsapp WPH* the second article is **not working**. The first article refers to android. Although the steps can be done in WIndows 10 mobile there is **no ogwhatapp for Windows 10 mentioned there.** This renders both the links useless.

Comment: @KolappanNathan whatsapp mod doesn't work, not even on interop unlocked phones , that app is crap

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can run two whatsapp applications on a windows phone. Tutorials are there but none of them work, I've tried it all. the cracked xaps of whatsapp doesn't deploy onto phone.

Comment: Seems true........but not sounds good

Answer (score -2):

You should to extract application and do some changes in it.
Change the name WhatsApp to WhatsApp1
From the source code and then change the version also.
Now compress the file with right extension as it was before.
Done.....

Comment: Can you expand your answer? How does one "extract application"? What changes should be done? Where in the source code should the name be changed? How is the changed app to be deployed back to the phone?