# How to be a beta tester?

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, beta

How to be a beta tester? [Here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/how-to-use-dual-whatsapp-in-lumia-535-running-wp8-1) my question is answered that unless you are a beta tester. So my question is that how can I be a beta tester to test beta apps. Alsoo I have multiple lumia phones some running WP8.1 and some W10M. So can I run beta apps on lumias running insider preview of W10M? More specifically how to download and install beta versions of apps?

Comment: Do you want to be beta tester for apps or for W10M ?

Comment: To be a beta tester for apps, you need to connect with the developer of the app in question, as each developer may have different methods/criteria for this, this is far too broad to cover here.

Comment: So @RowlandShaw should I limit my question to an specific question?